# Need Regular Expression for this(C#)

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

**Updated::**


**Password strength:**

Contain characters from three of the following four categories:

- English uppercase characters (A through Z)
- English lowercase characters (a through z)
- Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
- Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %

IS it possible to compare two fields value(entered) with regex...if yes then please add onr another condition to above list.

- compare password with username entered they must be different

Comment: Single regular expression a must? Regular expression is finite-automata processor and your requirement should require at least a push-down-automata processor.

Comment: it will be far simple using String methods.

Comment: Need a single reg exp for all this(mentioned above)

Comment: Does it need to be a regular expression because you are using it with a Membership Provider?

Comment: yup so that i can assigned it(req exp) to PasswordStrengthRegularExpression. Here is the link to let you know what i am saying http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2005/12/05/432359.aspx

Comment: Does it **have** to be three out of four?or can it be also four out of four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it in one expression it should be something like this:

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])).{8,}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vlnj)

Positive lookaheads (the `(?=.*[a-z])`) are used to check if the string contains the character group you want.

The problem here is, you want 3 out of 4, that means you have to make an alternation with all the allowed combinations.

The last part `.{8,}` is then matching the string and checking for at least 8 characters.

`^` and `$` are anchors, that anchor the pattern to the start and the end of the string.

`[!%,.;:]` is a character class, here you can add all the characters you want to include. Maybe its simpler to use a Unicode script like `\p{P}` for all punctuation characters. For more details see here on [regular-expresssions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

**Update**

> compare password with username entered they must be different

normally you should be able to build up your regular expression using string concatenation. I have no idea how it is in your case where you put the regex ...

Something like this (pseudo)

```
String Username = "FooBar";
regex = "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:]))(?i)(?!.*" + Username + ").+$";
```

I used here also an inline modifier `(?i)` to match it case independent. The `(?!.*` is the start of negative lookahead, meaning the string should not contain ...

Comment: String might hold at most 4 and at least 3 condition mentioned above....and skip atleast 8 char long condition

Comment: If you don't need the length check, just replace the `{8,}` with a `+` for at least one or a `*` which would also accept the empty string. And it will check for at least 3 conditions. It does not hurt if all 4 conditions are met.

Comment: @JonSkeet seems that this part has been removed from the question.

Comment: @stema: Ah yes, you're right. I do hate it when questions are updated with no indication to those who've already answered...

Comment: @Kannas care to be more specific?

Comment: stema let me know if it is possible to match text of two properties with regex.//last condition

Comment: I afraid!! It works with ASP .Net Membership passwordStrengthRegularExpression provider?? Any help in that context

Comment: @Kannas yes, `+` is one or more, `*` is zero or more

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This answer was written before the question was edited. It originally included the requirement to not include the user's account name, and be at least 8 characters long.

Given that you need to use the user's account name as part of it anyway, is there any reason you particularly want to do this as a regular expression? You may want to use regular expressions to express the patterns for the four categories (although there are other ways of doing it too) but I would write the rules out separately. For example:

```
// Categories is a list of regexes in this case. You could easily change
// it to anything else.
int categories = Categories.Count(regex => regex.IsMatch(password));
bool valid = password.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1
          && password.Length >= 8
          && categories >= 3;
```